# Parallax image problem

Tags: images, css, html

I am trying to replace the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVlU0.jpg (wont let me upload it to here for some reason) with another image but whenever I do it it just seems to make the background white and not actually do anything. 
The way I change them is by uploading the image to the WordPress media library and replacing the image name with the other image name.

**My Questions:**

Am I doing something wrong when trying to upload?

Is my image sized wrong?

(I'm running WordPress on academyofperformancearts.com.)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong but can't really assist without more information. I'm thinking it's either a theme, plugin, or server issue.

First try disabling the cherry lazy load / parallax plugins to see if it is coming from there.

Then try changing your theme to see if you have the same problem with media uploading.

Dont want to leave you with nothing so if you want you can try a temporary fix thorugh CSS, if your HTML is:

```
<div class="parallax-bg" data-parallax-type="image" data-img-url="https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg" data-speed="1.5" data-invert="false" style="width: 1350px; margin-left: -675px; left: 50%;"><div class="parallax-img parallax-bg-inner" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg&quot;); width: 1417px; height: 672px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -33.5px; top: -111px;"></div></div>
```

or

```
<div class="parallax-img parallax-bg-inner" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://academyofperformancearts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg&quot;); width: 1417px; height: 672px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -33.5px; top: -111px;"></div>
```

Then you can change it by uploading your image of choice in your media library and then forcing it through css like:

```
.parallax-bg{
background-image: url(http://inserturlhere.com/pic.jpg) !important;
}
```

or

```
.parallax-img .parallax-bg-inner{
background-image: url(http://inserturlhere.com/pic.jpg) !important;
}
```

Hopefully it puts you in the right direction, if none of it helps then I suggest taking your query to http://www.getmotopress.com/forums/topic/ because it seems it might be coming from something they developed.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload media to Wordpress it automatically dumps the media into a specific file.  The file path for your image is

/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/parallax-img-940x446-1.jpg

If you are uploading a new image today it will most likely go into the file /wp-content/uploads/2016/12/. When you are replacing the image you will need to make sure the new image is not only named the same but is in those corresponding folders.  To answer your questions:

1) What you are trying to do should work.  A white background would mean that the original image has been removed/renamed so something is definitely changing.

2) The current image is 1042x494px.  If you want your new image to match you'll want to make sure it is the same size.

Most Wordpress themes have a way to manage specific images like this on the page.  I didn't see anything mentioning what theme you were using but I would recommend looking into the theme documentation and seeing if they have suggestions for updating that image.  Really you shouldn't need to rename the file like that, you should just be able to put the new file where you want it.